# How to edit the google description of your site?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I know that `<meta name="Description" content="[description here]" />` can be used but I wonder how to make a description like the one in facebook.

[image: facebook]

Does this description use the `<meta>` tag as well? Or is there some other secret behind it?

Edit: I code my site by myself (no wordpress and stuff) :)

Comment: Go to Facebook -> Right click -> View source

Comment: Have you checked the source?

Comment: If you're referring to the subpages in the search result, I believe that's done on Google's side.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the website popularity.
Google does it, you don't.
[Google may do it but you can persuade them.](http://honestwebsitemarketing.com/adding-sub-links-sitelinks-results-google-search/)
And check this out [sub sitelinks in google search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745233/sub-sitelinks-in-google-search-result)

> 1. For starters, be sure you have a “sitemap.xml” file.  This is a file
>      that tells the search engine about the pages on your site and makes
>      it easier for its spiders to crawl and understand it.  Your
>      webmaster or website provider or Content Management System (like
>      WordPress) should have handled this for you, but it’s worth
>      checking.  If you’re not a master of website technical stuff,
>      whoever is your technical support person will be able to tell you if
>      that page is there, and properly set up.
> 2. You should register your site with Google Webmaster Tools, if you
>      haven’t already.  The exact process changes from time to time, but
>      basically, you’ll give Google the URL of your Sitemap file, which
>      you’ll have from the previous step.  You’ll have to put a “Site
>      Verification Code” on your site to prove to them that you own the
>      site, and there are a few other simple steps.
> 3. Whenever you link one page to another in your site, use anchor text
>      and alt text that’s descriptive, and as succinct as possible, and
>      consistent.  For example, you’ve linked to your “concierge services”
>      page from another page using the anchor text “concierge services.” 
>      That’s perfect.  Now, don’t link from another page using “guest
>      services.”  You don’t want to be confusing the poor Google spider,
>      after all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is how it happens.

> Google primarily displays multi link listings when they feel a query
>   has a strong chance of being navigational in nature. I think they can
>   determine that something is navigational in nature based on linkage
>   data and click streams. If the domain is well aligned with the term
>   that could be another signal to consider.
>
> If you have 10,000 legit links for a term that nobody else has more
>   than a few dozen external citations for then odds are pretty good that
>   your site is the official brand source for that term. I think overall
>   relevancy as primarily determined by link reputation is the driving
>   factor for weather or not they post mini site map links near your
>   domain.
>
> This site ranks for many terms, but for most of them I don't get the
>   multi link map love. For the exceptionally navigational type terms
>   (like seobook or seo book) I get multi links.
>
> The mini site maps are query specific. For Aaron Wall I do not get the
>   mini site map. Most people usually refer to the site by it's domain
>   name instead of my name.
>
> Google may also include subdomains in their mini sitemaps. In some
>   cases they will list those subdomains as part of the mini site map and
>   also list them in the regular search results as additional results.
>
> Michael Nguyen put together a post comparing the mini site maps to
>   Alexa traffic patterns. I think that the mini site maps may roughly
>   resemble traffic patterns, but I think the mini links may also be
>   associated with internal link structure.
>
> For instance, I have a sitewide link to my sales letter page which I
>   use the word testimonials as the anchor text. Google lists a link to
>   the sales letter page using the word testimonials.
>
> When I got sued the page referencing the lawsuit got tons and tons of
>   links from many sources, which not only built up a ton of linkage
>   data, but also sent tons of traffic to that specific page. That page
>   was never listed on the Google mini site map, which would indicate
>   that if they place heavy emphasis on external traffic or external
>   linkage data either they try to smooth the data out over a significant
>   period of time and / or they have a heavy emphasis on internal
>   linkage.
>
> My old site used to also list the monthly archives on the right side
>   of each page, and the February 2004 category used to be one of the
>   mini site map links in Google.
>
> You should present the pages you want people to visit the most to
>   search bots the most often as well. If you can get a few extra links
>   to some of your most important internal pages and use smart channeling
>   of internal linkage data then you should be able to help control which
>   pages Google picks as being the most appropriate matches for your mini
>   site map.
>
> Sometimes exceptionally popular sites will get mini site map
>   navigational links for broad queries. SEO Chat had them for the term
>   SEO, but after they ticked off some of their lead moderators they
>   stopped being as active and stopped getting referenced as much. The
>   navigational links may ebb and flow like that on broad generic
>   queries. For your official brand term it may make sense to try to get
>   them, but for broad generic untargeted terms in competitive markets
>   the amount of effort necessary to try to get them will likely exceed
>   the opportunity cost for most webmasters.

[Source](http://www.seobook.com/archives/001625.shtml).

Hope this helps.